# Django database function to extract week from date (if week starts on Saturday)

Tags: django, django-orm, django-database-functions

```
    loads_of_dedicated_customers = Load.objects.filter(customer__is_dedicated=True).exclude(load_status='Cancelled').values('customer__name').annotate(year=ExtractYear('drop_date'), week=ExtractWeek('drop_date').annotate(
        loads_count=Count('id'),
        sum_revenue = Sum('billable_amount'),
        sum_miles = Sum('total_miles'),
        rate_per_mile = ExpressionWrapper(F('sum_revenue') / NullIf(F('sum_miles'), 0), output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)),
    )
```

I have this query that groups by year and week. However, I need the results by week where the week starts on Saturday. Is there a simple way to do this or should I create a week columns in the table and save it there?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "where week starts on Saturday"?

Comment: There's another query that groups the Load objects by year and week. But the company that I'm doing this project for counts their week starting on Saturday, so the aggregates i.e. sum_revenue has to Sum the billable_amount for loads from Saturday to next Friday.